# Transfer someone else's NFT asset with an approve

Tags: nft, erc-721, transfer

I got this NFT marketplace smart contract. Still at the proof of concept stage, so I got 2 options to go with, I was just wondering if someone tried, or has knowledge about it:

Here is the deal, I was thinking, when a user creates an item listing, instead of locking their listed item in my marketplace contract (user transfers it to the contract address), which is the mentioned option one, what if I cut down that process by letting them keep their NFT item, until someone purchases it, then transferring given NFT from sellers address to whoever bought it.

**Now the question is (and it's a tricky one) if it's even possible to let the seller approve my marketplace contract on a given NFT item (when they create a listing) that I can use to process transferFrom function from seller address to buyer address when a buyer clicks on purchase function.**

Will approval make that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. You need to get approval on the target contract. The function looks like this:

```
approve(address to, uint256 tokenId)
```

> Approves another address to transfer the given token ID The zero
> address indicates there is no approved address. There can only be one
> approved address per token at a given time. Can only be called by the
> token owner or an approved operator.

More details: [OpenZeppelin ERC721 Docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721-approve-address-uint256-)